# How to use Scala Virtualized in a Maven project with Scala-2.10?

Tags: scala, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, scala-2.10

I would like to use [Scala Virtualized](https://github.com/tiarkrompf/scala-virtualized/wiki) in a Maven based Scala-2.10 project. The Scala Virtualized wiki only has instructions for SBT which suggest you only need to channge `scalaOrganization` from "org.scala-lang" to "org.scala-lang.virtualized" in build.sbt. This would suggest that for maven you need to change the `<groupId>` of scala-library in the pom.xml files. It seems that the Scala Maven plugin figures out what scala-compiler to get from the scala library you use, since I see no mention of scala-compiler in any of our pom.xml files. In any case changing the groupId of scala-library in the pom.xml files by itself does not work.
I did make sure to have the scala-library varsion in the parent pom.xml correspond to a version that exists for Scala Virtualized (2.10.2-RC1).

What (else) do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a ticket here: http://goo.gl/anZyE
and prepared a patch here: http://goo.gl/U43qs
anyone to test it ?

Comment: I am running into [issue #70](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/70). We were on maven-scala-plugin-2.15.2. If I just upgrade to the released scala-maven-plugin-3.1.5 the build fails because it does not seem to be able to see some of the classes. If I update our pom.xml with the currently recommended `<plugin>` declaration. then I get `duplicate class` error for one of our test classes both in 2.15.2 and 3.1.5. The pom.xml difference that brings about issue #70 is the `<goal>add-source</goal>` line inside the `process-resources` phase. Our project build on 2.15.2 without it.

Answer (score 1):

the groupId of scala-library, scala-compiler is [hard-coded into the plugin](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/scala_maven/ScalaMojoSupport.java#L52). The informations (version, ...) of scala-compiler are computed from the scala-library dependencies.

You can open a [ticket](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues) and ask to support other groupId (may be configurable one or not hard-coded). You can fork, made the change, and submit a patch / pull request.

**UPDATE** : scala-mavent-plugin 3.1.6 include the patch from evantill (thanks)
So you can override the default [scalaOrganization](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#scalaOrganization)